# Probability of the same position!

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

If we have $n$ different boxes in a room, each with $x$ slots (positions $1,2,\ldots,x$) each and we have $(x-1)$ red balls and $1$ white ball in each box on different slots. What is the probability that more than $y$ balls are at the same slot position in the whole room?

Comment: There is one special case, namely where all white balls are in the same slot.  Apart from that, you are looking for the distribution of $x-W$, where $W$ is the number of different positions occupied by white balls.  This is an occupancy problem, so may involve Stirling numbers of the second kind

Answer (score 0):

You have $n$ boxes, each with $x$ slots. We can now ask for the probability to find exactly $y$ white balls at a given slot. Note that it doesn't matter which slot we choose. We have a probability of $p=1/x$ to find the white ball for each box. The problem can be described via the [Binomial distribution.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution)
The probability to find exactly $y$ white balls in $n$ boxes with a probability of $p$ for each single box is
\begin{align}
f(y,n,p) = \begin{pmatrix} n \\ y\end{pmatrix}p^y(1-p)^{n-y}
\end{align}
If we want to know with which probability we get more than $y$ white balls, we simply add up all corresponding probabilities.
\begin{align}
f(\text{more than }y,n,p) = \sum_{j=y+1}^n f(j,n,p)
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply!. I think in the sum, you mean j = y + 1 to n.